# Como não atualizar página ao fechar um modalPanel do RichFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, rich-faces

Preciso que ao fechar um modalPanel do RichFaces a página na qual o modal foi chamado não seja renderizada.

A ação para fechar o `modalPanel` está assim:

```xml
<h:commandLink onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('modalRegistroItemAnalise');">
    <h:graphicImage value="/img/delete2.jpg" width="15"></h:graphicImage>
</h:commandLink>
```

Quando estou clicando no botão fechar ao retornar à página ela está sendo renderizada e estou usando abas, ao renderizar a página está voltando para a primeira aba.

Como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Para não renderizar toda página basta aplicar o `return false` na sentença.

```
<h:commandLink onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('modalRegistroItemAnalise'); return false;">
      <h:graphicImage value="/img/delete2.jpg" width="15"></h:graphicImage>
</h:commandLink>
```